# multiple (?vlc?) videos on the one screen

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc

I would like to display (say 4) videos on the one screen.  I have planned to use vlc running in an xterm.  This would have given me access to the geometry X operations to put the xterm windows where I need them - and then have vlc running in each xterm.

But vlc does not seem to work like that?? Whenever I run vlc it uses the entire screen.  And, not being and X application, does not appear to have (x,y) (width,height) type parameters.

I can program in C OK, I get by with html, perl does not phase me, never liked python - can anybody suggest a way to get 4 videos looking in their own quadrant of a PI screen?

Comment: OK, I did not express this well - I want to have a script run at startup and open (say) 4 wondows;  each window to display 1 or more mp4 videos.

Running the videos inside a web-browser does not allow them to scale up...

Comment: Hello Doc; this question is "off-topic" for raspberry Pi. I suggest you delete your question here, and try one of the other SEs: `Unix&Linux`, or maybe `Super User`.

Answer (score 0):

Understood about being off topic - but I needed sombody who knew about vlc and PIs.  Seemed a sensible place to ask.  There was lots of other PI and vlc stuff about - but mainly multiple screens.

Anyway mplayer -geometry 1500x1000+1500+1000 video.mp4 loop
allows you to place a display anywhere  on a single screen.  I can play 4 videos - each in a quarter screen on a PI4 - with no jitter.